# Why my MSBuild can't recognize existent path

Tags: msbuild

I cloned a vulkan toturial from github. And when I tried to build and run it in VS2019, it occurs the warning MSB8064 and MSB8065

```
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\vs c++\VulkanTutorial-main\VulkanTutorial-main\build\CMakeFiles\44aea1072fb14e925e4726f6994ec725\shaders.rule" succeeded, but the specified output "d:\vs c++\vulkantutorial-main\vulkantutorial-main\build\15_hello_triangle\shaders" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to malfunction.
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): warning MSB8064: Custom build for item "D:\vs c++\VulkanTutorial-main\VulkanTutorial-main\build\CMakeFiles\40637c6e00a0bab516ce3bb4bf5c7ebe\frag.spv.rule" succeeded, but the specified dependency "d:\vs c++\vulkantutorial-main\vulkantutorial-main\build\15_hello_triangle\shaders" does not exist. This may cause incremental build to malfunction."
```

There is a function readFile() in the code to read the shader files. After cmake build, the shader files do exist in the filesystem: "D:\vs c++\VulkanTutorial-main\VulkanTutorial-main\build\15_hello_triangle\shaders\vert.spv" and "D:\vs c++\VulkanTutorial-main\VulkanTutorial-main\build\15_hello_triangle\shaders\frag.spv", but the function call

```
auto vertShaderCode = readFile("shaders/vert.spv");
auto fragShaderCode = readFile("shaders/frag.spv");
```

did not find the shader files. But if I use the absolute path like

```
auto vertShaderCode = readFile("D:/vs c++/VulkanTutorial-main/VulkanTutorial-main/build/15_hello_triangle/shaders/vert.spv");
auto fragShaderCode = readFile("D:/vs c++/VulkanTutorial-main/VulkanTutorial-main/build/15_hello_triangle/shaders/frag.spv");
```

the shader files can be loaded correctly.

Does anyone knows why the program can't recognize the relative path?

I tried to use VS2022, and it still doesn't work, it looks like VS version is not the problem. What bothered me is that the path reported in warning MSB8064 and MSB8065 does exist, but my VS build system can't recognize it. I did't change other parts of this vulkan toturial project, because I found no one else reported this issue on its github issue page.

And here are contents of CMakeList.txt of this project, which I guess may be helpful

```
function (add_shaders_target TARGET)
  cmake_parse_arguments ("SHADER" "" "CHAPTER_NAME" "SOURCES" ${ARGN})
  set_source_files_properties(${SHADERS_DIR} PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC 1)
  set_source_files_properties(${SHADER_CHAPTER_NAME} PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC 1)
  set (SHADERS_DIR ${SHADER_CHAPTER_NAME}/shaders)
  add_custom_command (
    OUTPUT ${SHADERS_DIR}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${SHADERS_DIR}
    )
  set (SHADERS ${SHADERS_DIR}/frag.spv ${SHADERS_DIR}/vert.spv)
  # Some chapters may have compute shaders in addition to vertex and fragment shaders,
  # so we conditionally check this and add them to the target
  string(FIND "${SHADER_SOURCES}" "${CHAPTER_SHADER}.comp" COMPUTE_SHADER_INDEX)
  if (${COMPUTE_SHADER_INDEX} GREATER -1)  
    set (SHADERS ${SHADERS} ${SHADERS_DIR}/comp.spv)
  endif()
  add_custom_command (
    OUTPUT ${SHADERS}
    COMMAND glslang::validator
    ARGS --target-env vulkan1.0 ${SHADER_SOURCES} --quiet
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${SHADERS_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${SHADERS_DIR} ${SHADER_SOURCES}
    COMMENT "Compiling Shaders"
    VERBATIM
    )
  add_custom_target (${TARGET} DEPENDS ${SHADERS})
endfunction ()
```

Comment: This is purely a suspicion but, have you tried renaming the folder from `vs c++` to `vs cpp`?

Comment: I tried to put this project into a new folder with a simple name, but it still not work: "D:\visual statio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): warning MSB8065: 项“D:\Test\build\CMakeFiles\95d24b10e8348fd8141dc6104fbd1dc4\shaders.rule”的自定义生成成功，但尚未创建指定的输出“d:\test\build\15_hello_triangle\shaders”。这可能会导致增量生成无法正常工作。
1>D:\visual statio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): warning MSB8064: 项“D:\Test\build\CMakeFiles\eaa769cc2cb41e9d1c2ba885d13ae2cb\frag.spv.rule”的自定义生成成功，但指定的依赖项“d:\test\build\15_hello_triangle\shaders”不存在。这可能会导致增量生成无法正常工作。"